# Get ID or position of listview text

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with my Listview with 3 textviews when I use a ClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  ...
}
```

I can't find out which textview is clicked.

And when I use a onClick-Method with

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listview_text3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="onClickMenge"/>
```

and

```
public void onClickMenge(View view) {
  ...
}
```

I know which textview is clicked but I can´t get the id (Database-ID).

I read and tried but with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: So your ListView is a custom ListView. Are you using your own adapter for that ?

Comment: do you mean textview id?

Comment: first get item position: `ListView#getPositionForView`, then get item id: `Adapter#getItemId` (i am assuming that you use a `CursorAdapter` so `Adapter#getItemId` returns a right value)

Comment: Thanks @pskink. So easy! ;-)

Comment: sure,  you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

The int position in the on item click listener is the position of ur text view it starts from 0,1,2,3

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          if(pos==0)
          {
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);
            txt.setText("abc");
          }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue here:

- If you have data in your database tables, you simply need to create a class like this :

  ```
  public class ListItem {
     //define variables here
     private long id;
     private String itemName;

     //define constructor and getters and setters here;
  }
  ```

Now, when you provide the data to your adapter, you pass to each object instance an id;

Next, when a user clicks on the item in your list, you use the `position` provided to you by the `onClickListener` interface, to get the item from your `Adapter`then get the `id` as you wish!

I hope this makes sense and helps you get the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use your Cursor to find the id, using the position that onClickListener returns.

(...)

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     String[] column = new String[]{"_id"};
     Cursor cursor = db.query("name_of_table", column, null, null, null, null, null, null);
     cursor.move(position+1); 
     long id = cursor.getLong(0);
```

(...)

You need to connect your database with variable db.

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
BDCore xDB = new BDCore(context);
db = xDB.getWritableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onClick and position from getView method of your adapter

int **itemPosition** = -1;

Now set itemPosition in getView method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   itemPosition  = position;
}

 public void onClickMenge(View view) {

      int viewId = view.getId();//ID of text view clicked
      //Use itemPosition  now
 }
```